# UVa 227 (Puzzle) Wrong Answer Despite Passing All Provided Test Cases

Tags: c++

Here is the simple code which I submitted to UVa Online Judging for Qn 227. (Puzzle) I have tested with various test cases including those from debug.org but still the submission yields "wrong answer". If anyone could point out where the error may lie in the code or just give a test case with which the programme will give wrong answer, it will be greatly appreciated.

```
//puzzle
#define LOCAL
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 5

int read(char s[MAX][MAX])
{
    int blank=0;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            s[i][j]=getchar();
            if(i==0&&j==0&&s[i][j]=='Z')
                return -1;
            else if(s[i][j]==' ')
                blank=i*10+j;
        }
        for(;getchar()!='\n';);
    }
    return blank;
}

int write(char s[MAX][MAX], int blank)
{
    char n;
    while((n=getchar())!='0')
    {
        int c1=(blank/10)%10, c2=blank%10;
        if(n=='\n')
            continue;
        else if(n=='A')
        {
            if(c1==0)
            {
                for(;getchar()!='\n';);
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                s[c1][c2]=s[c1-1][c2];
                s[c1-1][c2]=' ';
                blank-=10;
            }
        }
        else if(n=='B')
        {
            if(c1==4)
            {
                for(;getchar()!='\n';);
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                s[c1][c2]=s[c1+1][c2];
                s[c1+1][c2]=' ';
                blank+=10;
            }
        }
        else if(n=='L')
        {
            if(c2==0)
            {
                for(;getchar()!='\n';);
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                s[c1][c2]=s[c1][c2-1];
                s[c1][c2-1]=' ';
                blank-=1;
            }
        }
        else if(n=='R')
        {
            if(c2==4)
            {
                for(;getchar()!='\n';);
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                s[c1][c2]=s[c1][c2+1];
                s[c1][c2+1]=' ';
                blank+=1;
            }
         }
    else
        {
            for(;getchar()!='\n';);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    for(;getchar()!='\n';);
    return 1;
}
int main()
{
    #ifdef LOCAL
        freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);
        freopen("output.txt","w",stdout);
    #endif
    char s[MAX][MAX];
    memset(s,'\0',sizeof(s));
    int blank, kase=0;
    while((blank=read(s))!=-1)
    {
        if(kase++)
            printf("\n");
        printf("Puzzle #%d:\n",kase);
        if(write(s, blank))
        {
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
                    printf("%c ",s[i][j]);
                printf("%c\n",s[i][4]);
            }
            continue;
        }
        else
            printf("This puzzle has no final configuration.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `read` and `write` are POSIX functions, perhaps call your functions something else in case the judge has a conflict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the event that the input contains an invalid move, your `write()` function consumes the rest of that line of input and returns.  But the moves for a given puzzle are explicitly permitted to span multiple lines, so your approach does not necessarily consume all of the remaining moves for the puzzle.  If it does not, then you start interpreting the remaining unconsumed moves as the start of the next puzzle.  The sample cases do not include such an example.